# How responsiveness is in contradiction with throughput in zen-kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

At [this link](https://liquorix.net/#features) a table is given for detail of **Zen Interactive Tuning** and at this link and on [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Kernels&oldid=407966#Official_packages) it said:

> **Zen Interactive Tuning**: Tunes the kernel for responsiveness at the cost of throughput and power usage.

More this means tuning responsiveness costs for throughput. On the other hand when we see the table given below the we see that for example scheduling latency has decreased which means that throughput may get higher too. Other changes in configs seem to be have direct relation with throughput too.
On a larger scale responsiveness has to have direct relation with throughput too.
The zen-kernel says that it has a higher throughput too.
Then why it is said that responsiveness has been reached at the cost of throughput?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little difficult to understand. You linked the Liquorix kernel and then you talk about the Zen kernel, and you mention the Zen kernel in your title.

I am going to assume you are comparing the Liqorix kernel with the stable Linux kernel since you are talking about information from that link, and you just have the names confused.
The Liqorix kernel and zen kernel have similar goals which are to achieve a lower latency (more responsiveness), but that is not to say that throughput can also be achieved by tuning the kernel.

Higher throughput **and** lower latency are of course achievable but this comes at the cost of removing kernel features.

When it mentions that responsiveness is achieved at the cost of throughput, it is probably talking about the ratio of throughput to latency.
An optimized kernel will probably have a bit more of both, but the zen and Liquorix kernels will have a ratio skewed towards latency.

I can try to clarify my answer if you need me to.

Comment: I'd be happy if you make the clarification.   You are right. I've set the link to another kernel. According to [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Kernels&oldid=407966#Official_packages) "Zen Interactive Tuning" is common in both of them, hence we are on the correct path.

Comment: What I am getting at, is that the kernels are optimized for speed, and specifically low latency. Tuning the kernel changes parameters, and you could target high throughput, which would lower the responsiveness. This kind of defeats the purpose of using those kernels, however, since they are better for low latency. There are kernels made for high throughput, or you could "tune" the stable Linux kernel by building it from the source and changing the flags. The Linux kernel provides a balance between throughput and latency, to adequately support systems with multiple uses.

Comment: Is it correct to consume that context switch rate may get less? @the_hobbinord

Comment: A higher context switch rate increases latency. So to increase responsiveness, these kernels will probably have a slower context switch rate. They are meant for gaming and multimedia creation so multithreading really won't be a goal with these kernels. Most games and video/audio software only utilize the number of physical CPU cores.